react storybook not working with relative path import
I tried implement strory book to current react-typescript project. I installed storybook 8.2.2.
In the projects all import are made by absolute imports, such as src/components/Button, not by relative way ../components/Button. As I read on here, storybook uses relative imports by default and should change it absolute path in case of projects using absolute imports.
This is my Button.stories.ts
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/react'
import { fn } from '@storybook/test'

import Button from 'src/components/cta/button/Button'

const meta = {
  title: 'Example/CustomButton',
  component: Button,
  parameters: {
    layout: 'centered'
  },
  tags: ['autodocs'],
  argTypes: {
    label: { control: 'text' }
  },
  args: { onClick: fn() }
} satisfies Meta<typeof Button>

export default meta
type Story = StoryObj<typeof meta>

export const Primary: Story = {
  args: {
    label: 'Send Request',
    name: 'create-request-btn',
    type: 'default'
  }
}


my .storybook/main.ts
import type { StorybookConfig } from '@storybook/react-webpack5'
import path from 'path'

const config: StorybookConfig = {
 webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    if (config.resolve) {
      config.resolve.modules = [...(config.resolve.modules || []), path.resolve(__dirname, '../src')]
    }
    return config
  },
  stories: ['../src/**/*.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/preset-create-react-app',
    '@storybook/addon-onboarding',
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@chromatic-com/storybook',
    '@storybook/addon-interactions'
  ],
  framework: {
    name: '@storybook/react-webpack5',
    options: {}
  },
  staticDirs: ['..\\public']
}
export default config


and in tsconfig.json my baseUrl: "."
I tried in .storybook/main.ts
 webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    if (config.resolve) {
      config.resolve.modules = [...(config.resolve.modules || []), path.resolve(__dirname, '../src')]
    }
    return config
  },

but still got same error which is
ERROR in ./src/stories/Button.stories.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'src/components/cta/button/Button' in 'C:\Users\user\Projects\storybook-fe\src\stories'
